# C# Running Batch File Gets Some Errors

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a server program for Minecraft. And I make a form with Visual Studio, I added a button named "Start Server".

"Start Server" Buttons Code:

```
Process.Start("C:\\Users\\w7\\Desktop\\UxMux Server\\start.bat");
```

This code works very well to open Batch File. I can start my server. But, on batch file opened I get this errors:
[image: Getting error from batch file]

But if I start batch file manually, I don't get any errors. But if I am start the batch file I get errors.

My "start.bat" Batch File Codes:

```
@echo off
title Minecraft Plugin Test Server
mode 1000
java -Xms328M -Xmx328M -jar spigot.jar nogui
PAUSE
```

The program pictures ( Note: Buttons Named Turkish, Beacuse I Am Turkish )
[image: The program picture]

I can't find any solution for this system.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you use *Process.Start()*, with *UseShellExecute* set to *false*, it calls the Windows *CreateProcess()* API function. That function uses the PATH environment variable of the current process (your .NET app, not the one you want to launch. When is set to *true*, the *ShellExecute* function is used.

try, either

```
string path = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("path");
path += @";c:\your_nedded_path;";
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("path", path);
Process.Start("C:\\Users\\w7\\Desktop\\UxMux Server\\start.bat");
```

Or use, *ProcessStartInfo* structure

```
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
  WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Users\\w7\\Desktop\\UxMux Server",
  UseShellExecute = true,
  FileName  = "cmd",
  Arguments = "/c start.bat" // + parameters
};
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
p.Start();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And I want to ask another question. I opened the batch file. How to close already opened batch filed with button ?

Comment: you cannot interact with a cmd process, at least not in the way you are spawning it, but, once you have process `p`, `p.kill()`

Comment: I get this error:

System.InvalidOperationException

Comment: I've not a cristal ball, if you don't post your actuall code, there's no way I can figure out what's going on. but I bet you have gone out of scope